# Customize list from rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I have a `hotel` model and its attributes are:

`id, hotel_name, address, searchable.`

when I set searchable `false` for particular hotel then this hotel should not come in dropdown when i type in search field.

Controller is

```
class HotelsController < Admin::BaseController
  autocomplete :hotel, :hotel_name, :full => true
end
```

How can I optimize this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In your controller**

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = active_record_get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = items.where(searchable: true)
end
```

In the example above we call `active_record_get_autocomplete_items` rather than `super`; there is **no** super as these methods are called dynamically due to the design to handle multiple ORMs.  In the above example `ActiveRecord` is assumed, however `Mongoid` and `MongoMapper` are also both currently supported (as others may be in the future).  The example above will still work, but depending on the ORM you are using the call to `active_record_get_autocomplete_items(parameters)` would need to change to match your driver, for example it would become `mongo_mapper_get_autocomplete_items(parameters)` for the `MongoMapper` driver.

**Using scope**

```
autocomplete :hotel, :hotel_name, :full => true, :scopes => [:searchable_allow]
```

**In model**

```
 scope :searchable_allow, where(searchable: true)
```

Comment: Where is `get_autocomplete_items` called explicitly in the app? Or is a part of the autocomplete gem?

Comment: I cannot achieve it using scopes, only "get_autocomplete_items" solved it for me.