# Limit scope on rails-jquery-autocomplete (rails3-jquery-autocomplete) gem - where clause issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

There is a recommended solution and it seems to work.  The issue is in my where clause and I'm not sure what's wrong.
For reference, here is the solution(s):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250426/4379077
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7250341/4379077

I am trying to scope users that are members of the current_user's family tree memberships(branches) user's within my Nodes controller.  This would normally be done using this code (current_user.family_tree.memberships).

Note I have successfully set this up to autocomplete showing all users (User.all):

In my routes:

```
resources :nodes do
  get :autocomplete_user_first_name, :on => :collection
end
```

In my Node controller I have the following code:

```
autocomplete :user, :first_name, :extra_data => [:last_name, :email],
 display_value: :full_name
```

And in my view I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for node do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :user_tags %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :user_tags, autocomplete_user_first_name_nodes_path, 'data-auto-focus' => true, value: nil %>
  <%= f.submit %>  
<% end %>
```

When I attempt to add the recommended solution to my nodes controller:

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = super(parameters)
  items = items.where(:user_id => current_user.family_tree.memberships)
end
```

I get this message:
`NoMethodError - super: no superclass method "get_autocomplete_items" for #<NodesController:0x007fc516692278>:`

So, I found this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/18717327/4379077 and changed it to

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = active_record_get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  items = items.where(:user_id => current_user.family_tree.memberships)
end
```

It works, but I get the following error
`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column users.user_id does not exist`, so I changed the where clause to this `:id => current_user.family_tree.memberships` and I get this result

```
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  users.id, users.first_name, "users"."last_name",
"users"."email" 
FROM "users"  WHERE (LOWER(users.first_name) ILIKE 'mi%')
AND "users"."id" IN (SELECT "memberships"."id" FROM "memberships"  
WHERE "memberships"."family_tree_id" = $1)  
ORDER BY LOWER(users.first_name) ASC LIMIT 10  [["family_tree_id", 1]]
```

The issue is that I believe I need to get a collection within the membership model comparing the attribute `membership.user_id` to `user.id`.  What am I doing wrong in my where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are Membership objects the same thing as Users?

if not, you need to get the user_id off the membership record

This line would need to change

```
# use pluck to get an array of user_ids.
items = items.where(:id => current_user.family_tree.memberships.pluck(:user_id))
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to thank you in comments @swards, but you saved my sanity.  Thank you!

Comment: @swank, how would I add an AND onto this where clause where :full_name  is NOT contained within the node.user_tag_list collection?

Comment: Try editing this `autocomplete :user, :first_name, :extra_data => [:last_name, :email], display_value: :full_name` to see if you can fix it.  Configuring display value like it is will show the full name.  More here I think: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete